# How to split-view design and source in Netbeans GUI builder

Tags: swing, netbeans, gui-builder

Short and simple, is it possible to view the source and designer at the same time with Netbeans GUI builder?

Even if there's no real straightforward way, I would like to know if someone has any ideas for workarounds, like opening the form in multiple tabs for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the form so it's displayed.  Right click it's name tab and select clone.

[image]

You should now have two tabs with the same name, representing the same class.

On one of the tabs, click "Source".

Now you can "re-dock" the second/cloned view anywhere you want.

[image]

Comment: Dead simple. I didn't know the clone option existed. Thank you!

Comment: Love clone on multi-monitor systems :D